# Table "tablename" does not exist in moodle

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I am new in php cms(moodle). I create a plugin and it's name is `area`. i have installed it and database table created successfully, table name is `mdl_area_state`, but  giving me an error

> Table mdl_area_state does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the xmldb editor? This will create an install.xml file that will create the tables.

Go to site admin -> development -> xmldb editor

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor

The install file will be located in local/yourpluginname/db/install.xml.